# SQL removing duplicate based on actual/forecast

Tags: mysql

I have a table similar to below and was wondering if on days were there is an actual and forecast to remove the forecast row, and only keep the actuals?

[image]

Comment: [Formatted Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) are preferred to images of Tables as it can be [searched for and tested out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12892553) and in addition [Users from certain countries can't view hosted images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407369/12892553)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to union with an existence check

```
select date,type,value from t where type ='actual'
union all
select date,type,value from t where type ='forecast' 
and not exists (select 1 from t t1 where t1.date = t.date and t1.type = 'actual') ;
```

And since there is no guarantee that and actual will have a forecast or a forecast will have an actual this is a bit simpler than simulating a full join, though not necessarily quicker.

Comment: Thank you. That's worked a treat.